# HTMLExtra report is not generated in docker pipeline

Tags: postman, newman, postman-newman

For some reason after the node is upgraded to 16, reports stopped getting generated.

There is no error

node : 16
Newman : 5.3.2
htmlextra: 1.22.11

````
        collection: './test_suites/' + collectionFile,
        environment: './envs/' + environmentFile,
        workingDir: '.',
        reporters: ['cli', 'json', 'junit', 'htmlextra'],
        envVar: environmentVariables,
        delayRequest: 4000,
        timeoutRequest: 60000,
        timeout: 2500000,
        reporter:{
            // html: {
            //     export: reportNameHtml,
            //     template: './templates/api_automation.hbs'
            // },
            junit: {
                export: reportNameXml
            },
            htmlextra: {
                export: reportNameHtmlExtra
            }
        },
        function(err) {
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            console.log("Collection run is finished " + collectionFile);
        }
    });
}```
````